# Python Posix path cannot concatenate str

Tags: python

Using this piece of code, suggest me :

```
files = [item for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir() 
         if item.is_file()
         and item.name.startswith('str')]
```

I cannot use the element of list to concatenate the element ... this is the error :

```
   self.bins.append(np.genfromtxt('vorcospdf/56.72/'+j ,usecols=(0,), skip_header=0)) 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "PosixPath") to str
```

Comment: `np.genfromtxt()` appears nowhere in the piece of code that you show here. But evidently `j` is a `PosixPath` instance from pathlib.

Answer (score 2):

`files` is a list of `PosixPath` objects, not strings. Use `str()` to convert them to strings.

```
files = [str(item) for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir() 
         if item.is_file()
         and item.name.startswith('str')]
```